# How Do I Slow Only One Portion Of Code Without Slowing The Rest?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have tried using Sleep, Delay Functions, etc. These all slow the entire code down, as shown below. When only DoThis is True, it is printing numbers at the desired speed. When only DoThat is True, it is at the desired speed as well. However, when both run, the Sleep applies to the whole program and is clearly not the solution, only and example of what I need to do. Is there a way to slow down the output of DoThis and not the rest of the code/ allow the other code to run at the same time?

I need to:
Slow only the DoThis output
Do not change the UnchangeableValue
Have both DoThis and DoThat functions running at the same time

```
int main() {

    int True = 1;
    int UnchangebleValue = 1;

    int DoThis = 1;
    int DoThat = 1;

    while (DoThis >= True || DoThat <= True) {
        if (DoThis >= True) {
            DoThis += UnchangebleValue;
            cout << DoThis << endl;
            Sleep(1000); //Desired Effect, Needs to Apply Only Here
        }

        if (DoThat <= True) {
            DoThat -= UnchangebleValue;
            cout << DoThat << endl;
        }   
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Edit: Here is the code I want to accomplish using the thread suggestion. If there are better ways to do this I'm all ears. Thank you for the reply.

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    int True = 1;
    int UnchangebleValue = 1;

    int DoThis = 1;
    int DoThat = 1;

    std::thread t1([&DoThis, &DoThat, &UnchangebleValue, True]() {
        while (DoThis >= True ) {   
                DoThis += UnchangebleValue;
                std::cout << DoThis << std::endl;
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
        }
    });

    std::thread t2([&DoThis, &DoThat, &UnchangebleValue, True]() {
        while (DoThat <= True) {
                DoThat -= UnchangebleValue;
                std::cout << DoThat << std::endl;
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10000));
        }       
    });

    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you need threads.  Have one thread run the DoThis code, and the other thread run the DoThat code.

Answer (score 0):

I can't really understand your overall goal or logic.

But, if you want two pieces of code to run independently, you use threads. From C++11, you can do it in a standard way, with std::thread. I changed your code to make it run in threads (without understanding the goal). I used lambdas.

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    int True = 1;
    int UnchangebleValue = 1;

    int DoThis = 1;
    int DoThat = 1;

    std::thread t1([&DoThis, &DoThat, &UnchangebleValue, True]() {
        while (DoThis >= True || DoThat <= True) {
            if (DoThis >= True) {
                DoThis += UnchangebleValue;
                std::cout << DoThis << std::endl;
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
            }}
        });

    std::thread t2([&DoThis, &DoThat, &UnchangebleValue, True]() {
        if (DoThat <= True) {
            DoThat -= UnchangebleValue;
            std::cout << DoThat << std::endl;
        }});

    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Note that there is no synchronization in the code above. In a real project, you'd want atomic values, and/or mutexes (mutices).

Comment: While this isn't quite what I wanted to do, your code made it possible to complete my code. I worked ahead in my program and ended up tying the values to a clock time to get varying output times. I added an edit of how I re-did my example with your threads. Are there benefits or disadvantages to doing this with threads VS clock functions?

Comment: What do you want to do? As far as I'm concerned, thread is a good choice. Each thread can execute different tasks in parallel.